# Can I be tracked down using Tor after not using it again?

Tags: anonymity

I used Tor just some minutes ago to send highly sensitive data to the press. This could get me in serious trouble in my home country.

I send that data over a platform that normally connects people to sell private stuff. For that, to use the chat, I had to activate Javascript temporally (within Tor browser).

I used my regular internet connection to connect to the Tor network.

What I can say for sure:

- no one knew what I am doing at that moment so there is no current spy etc. on me
- All accounts needed for that process (selling portal and mail provider) were created using Tor as well
- javascript was activated for that

Should I worry?

This will come out for sure and investigations will come.

Comment: I think this is sort of off-topic for Tor (it's a more general information security question, it's equally valid for any anonymity software), but yes. The problem is: The set of people with the data is small, you used Tor once around the time that you use the data. If someone subpoenaed your internet connection records and saw you used Tor just before the leak and you were also one of the people who had the data then it might make you a likely candidate, see: [my write-up of this problem](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/tor-misconception/blob/master/README.md#acting-locally).

Answer (score 1):

Tor is probably one of your best options at being anonymous on the internet.  That being said there are always a possibility of being tracked.  For instance if you had your internet connection tapped before you started using tor and your exit node was one controlled by the same people (big if), they could potentially find out who you were by a throttling your connection in some sort of regular pattern and comparing it with the exit node you used.  In addition there is a small possibility of someone holding a zero day that would allow you to be deanonymized.  Or the version of Tor you downloaded could have been modified by a third party (assuming you didn't check the hash).  You would probably have to be a pretty wanted man for anyone to use any of these techniques though.

Again, Tor is one of your best bets, maybe in the future if you are more worried about it you could also use a anonymizing vpn (who have a canary that is not triggered) and a couple of other proxies.

Edit: not using it again is not really gonna help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you used tor?

First most if not all of tor's nodes get monitored.

Second most countries and ISP can determine that you used tor.

Third if you weren't detected yet now you are detectable because you posted here this question.

So for your question you should be worried but not as much as you think - if you'd use it once it's like finding a needle in a haystack.

For the future - i would suggest using proxy chain with hostile countries (iran, north korea, china, russia and etc).

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common way people using Tor or other masquerading protocols have been found is due to poor opsec. In fact a website on Tor network was cracked down "allegedly" since the owner used this very website to discuss changes in the website and eventually uploaded the changes (I'm truncating the actual story). Tor as a protocol is secure and compromise of the host is how a person is usually tracked. Use operating systems such as Tails (Google it).

What you and others should take away is the protocol is secure but your OPSEC determines the secrecy of your identity.